# My php-wordpress if while loop only runs the first time

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, while-loop

My code had a typo!
But im not allowed to delete this so here you have some info on ways you could have done a better job then me ;)

The problem is as follows, My query is skipping a part of my loop.
i have a query that makes a anchor with the title and thumbnail of the post.
it runs the query fine for the first post except for the second post it does not load in the thumbnail, but it does show the title, and the title is only mentioned after the thumbnail, There is no small image that resembles it cant be found either. My first question posted on here so apolagies for misplacing items in the wrong sections.

```
<?php


// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
'post_type'              => array( 'klantcase' ),
'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
'nopaging'               => true,
'order'                  => 'ASC',
'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
);

// The Query
$klantcases = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $klantcases->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $klantcases->have_posts() ) {
    $klantcases->the_post();
        echo "<a href=".get_the_permalink().">";
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size = 'post-thumbnail');?><br><?php
        echo the_title();?><br><?php
        echo "</a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "no posts found";
}
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now there is probably many ways to improve this loop but as mentioned im very new to all of this. That said i'd love to hear how you guys would resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure all posts have a thumbnail?

Comment: Yes i am positive, just double checked

Comment: What do you see in generated html?

Comment: simply the thumbnail and the title text underneath it, both clickable to the anchor link

Comment: Please don't edit/try to delete your solved questions; the major point of stack overflow is to keep questions and answers around for other developers with similar problems to find in the future.

Comment: Voting to close since it was a typo.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo since this was a typo, I would argue that it should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define empty variable on top of while loop.
And in loop concatenate your html with that empty variable.
For Example.

```
$output = '';
        if ( $klantcases->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $klantcases->have_posts() ) {
                $klantcases->the_post();
                $output .= '<a href="'.the_permalink().'">';
                $output .= the_post_thumbnail() .'<br>';
                $output .= the_title();
                $output .= '</a>';
            }
        } else {
            echo "no posts found";
        }

        echo $output;
```

Comment: Looks great, Still does not fix my problem, i'm seriously questioning my other parts of the code right now, as both suggestions apply fixes to parts of my faulty code. But neither of them show me any more then i had, After changing this in my code, i got the url and image seperately, then the title after that. Second post still just gave me the url of the singled out post

Comment: @Jochemdr send me your output data array.
simple print_r($klantcases); and send me that array.

Comment: I cannot find a way to send you a personal messages and the print_r is too long? if there is a way to privately message just message me and i'll the red dot pop up somewhere

Comment: print_r(serialize($klantcases)); it will reduce and wrap the text, then send me after you have printed out with this code.

Comment: Still too long, dont think it did much other than the regular serialize.

Comment: http://localhost/PE/wordpress/bakker-zonwering/Bakker Zonwerings:46:"
This is from the second item, no thumbnail and no 3rd and 4th post, but i suspect the other posts not showing up is another problem.


";

Comment: Ok, Just print out your data and see if values are presented in each index.
If the data is attach with all key value pairs then there will be some issue in code.

Comment: I have found the problem and i feel miserably retarded. The problem was lying in the naming of klantcases and klantcase, i used klantcases everywhere when the problem was in post-type klantcase , that had to be klantcases. Im sorry for beign the biggest coding idiot alive, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `echo the_title()` - it already echoes out, so I'm guessing that's where part of the problem is coming in. You can also make your loop a little more simple.

You don't need the `'post_status'` argument, as `publish` is default.

In your loop, let's use WP's built in echo functions: `the_permalink()`, `the_title()` and `the_post_thumbnail()`. You don't have to pass any arguments to the `the_post_thumbnail()` because you are just calling the default in your code.

```
<?php

// WP_Query arguments
$args = [
    'post_type'   => ['klantcase'],
    'nopaging'    => TRUE,
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
];

// The Query
$klantcases = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $klantcases->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $klantcases->have_posts() ) {
        $klantcases->the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><br>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    echo 'no posts found';
}
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This is a great pointer indeed, its double echo'ing the way i did it.
However this is a fix to my horrible code it did not fix my error yet.
I just get the first thumbnail + title as <a>, The 2nd post i only get the title, the 3rd &4th post dont show anything.

Comment: Edit your question to show the rendered HTML for the loop. That may help see what's happening. What you can also do, is remove things. Simply do this test - remove everything in your loop except for `<?php the_title(); ?>` See if you get 4 titles.

Comment: Good idea, will do.

Comment: I only got two titles, so ill continue to show what i get when i normally run it